# Not able to map a network drive using WshNetwork_Class.mapnetworkdrive in c#

Tags: c#

I have created a windows service to map a network drive.In Onstart method am trying to map the drive using below code

```
IWshNetwork_Class network = new IWshNetwork_Class();
network.MapNetworkDrive(drive, @remoteName, Type.Missing, UserName, Password]);
```

It always throws an exception as

> The local device name is already in use. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070055)."

But when i check with explorer the drive is not connected.When I map using mycomputer->map networkdrive am able to map it.
Please help me to sort this out.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{ 
  string drive = "Z:";
  string remote = @remoteName;
  if (!Directory.Exists(drive))
  {
     IWshNetwork_Class network = new IWshNetwork_Class();
     network.MapNetworkDrive(drive, @remoteName, Type.Missing, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"]);
  }
}
```

Comment: could you provide some more code plese

Comment: Please see the edited post for the code snippet.

Comment: That is ERROR_ALREADY_ASSIGNED, "The local device name is already in use".  You'll have to pick a different drive letter or (more likely) first unmap that drive letter.  Use the RemoveNetworkDrive() method.

Comment: @ Hans Passant that's exactly what i though... @kns Try changing letter for your drive.

Comment: Thanks for the responses..I have tried many number of random & free drive labels but no luck.After ensuring F: is free I tried to connect it but has thrown same exception as above and then tried using   network.RemoveNetworkDrive("F:", Type.Missing, Type.Missing); It has given me the error as"This network connection does not exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800708CA)".Hence RemoveNetworkDrive,MapNetworkDrive both are not able to find any network drives it seems.Please advice.

Comment: Just one quick update same code been placed in console project its able to map the drives.however Problem persists with the windows service application.This service is running under Network service account.

Comment: "when I check with explorer the drive is not connected" - network drives are a per-user concept. Unless you're looking at windows explorer using the same account that the service is running under, it's meaningless. Why can't the service do its work using UNC paths, and avoid the whole mapping in the first place?

Comment: Changed the installer account property to Local system.It is working fine.